# Accessing two HTTP servers on a LAN

Tags: networking, router, apache-http-server, port-forwarding, http

In my home, I have a single Comcast modem connected to a D-Link router.  The domain name myDomain.com points to my Comcast IP (yes, I know this is probably not okay, but I am only using it for personal testing with very little bandwidth, and have another server for production).  The router is connected to several PC clients and two Linux servers.  The Linux server static IPs are 192.168.0.200 and 192.168.0.201.

I've set up virtual server (i.e. port forwarding) to pass ports 21, 22, 80, 443, and 10000 to 192.168.0.200.

192.168.0.201 is just a PHP based fax server, and I wish to access it also using HTTP (i.e. Port 80).  But I can't use Port 80 since I am already using this port for 192.168.0.200.

So, would I just access the fax server using `http://myDomain.com:123/sendAFax.php` and create another virtual server to forward port 123 to 192.168.0.201?  Which port number should I use?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you using Apache? Reverse Proxy and subdomains is what you should use...... http://serverfault.com/questions/55846/running-multiple-publicly-accessible-web-servers-on-a-single-ip-address example - h**p://fax.myDomain.com/

Comment: Yes, I am using Apache.  Do you agree with Eccentropy's advice that I won't be able to use this solution with my existing configuration?

Comment: if I had the time I would go to turnkeylinux.org and get a virtual machine and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user1032531, you're on the right path.

You're using NAT on a home network,so you won't be able to use @Logman's solution since you're still dealing with port 80, and a single IP Address (COMCast's).

You could use any unassigned port such as 8080, 8888, etc.

Try this:

1. Forward port **8080** on your router to port **80** on **192.168.0.201**, and leave your **192.168.0.201** web server serving port **80**.
2. To access that server from the Internet, you'd use http://myDomain.com:8080/sendAFax.php. Port forwarding will take care of hooking up your external port 8080 to 192.168.0.201's port 80.

Comment: For some reason, I cannot access http://myDomain.com:8080 (FF gives me Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at myDomain.com:8080.).  I've turned of iptables and have selinux in permissive mode. For my router, I have IP Address as 192.168.0.201, public IP as 8080, and private IP as 80.  Any suggestions?  Thank you

Comment: Can you get to http://192.168.0.201 on the local LAN? A dumb question, but want to rule it out: Are you using DDNS (Dynamic DNS) on your router to update the public IP address for myDomain.com? Is the IP address correct? Can you try to hit http://myDomain.com:8080/sendAFax.php from a mobile device [not connected to your local LAN via WIFI] to make sure it isn't a client/browser issue?

Comment: I can access 192.168.0.201 on local LAN.  I am using DDNS.  IP is correct.  Mobile devices do not make a difference.  Note that I can access http://192.168.0.201/index.php but not http://192.168.0.201:8080/index.php.  Maybe I should make Apache listen to 8080 also?

Comment: You shouldn't need to make Apache listen on port 8080 if your port forward is set up correctly. For simplicity, you _could_ use only port 8080 on 192.168.0.201 instead of using port 80, and having the port forward from 8080 to 192.168.0.201:8080.

Comment: Had firewall issues, and once fixed, all worked like a charm.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out!